How to check if a debugger is attached to an Android process without using the Android Studio GUI?
I am trying to automate a test to check if a debugger is attached to my Android application. Currently, I can test it manually, but I would like to know how I can do this without using the Android Studio graphical interface.
The way my application checks if the debugger is attached is by reading the file proc//status, specifically the TraceId property.
I would like to know if there is a way to attach a debugger to an Android process programmatically or if there is a way to mock this debugger comportament. Any suggestions or code examples that could help me?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I tried using the jdb, but is missing something.
adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:<pid>
jdb -attach localhost:8000
It's open a jdb shell, but not change the TraceId property

Sometimes restarting your ADB server can help resolve connection issues. You can do this with:
adb kill-server
adb start-server

To check if the debugger is attached you can run:
jinfo <pid>


It's not about that, i can run the lldb to debug remotely, but in my case it's not useful because my tests run on sauce lab and have a lot of limitations on adb commands

The way I found is using the lldb debugger, i need to attach in a running proccess and forward the device port with the machine port, then run lldb and put the remote address on the port forwared.
In my case this work but not solve my problem, my tests runs on saucelab and there is a lot of limitations to adb commands.
